# How to send commands when opening a tmux session inside another tmux session?

Tags: shell, tmux

A typical situation may be:

```
$ tmux
  [0] $ ssh example.com
      $ tmux attach
        [0] $
```

I open a tmux session, then ssh in to a server and attach to an existing tmux session. At this point I have one tmux session inside another. How do I send commands to the inner tmux session?

Note: Both tmux sessions have the same key bindings.

Comment: not a programming question. Please try http://superuser.com/. Good luck.

Comment: I'm happy to ask for the question to be moved, however for context I use vim inside tmux to code and of course often have to ssh in to other servers which is where this problem occurs.

Answer (score 251, accepted):

The `send-prefix` command can be used to send your prefix keystroke to (the process running in) the active pane. By default, the prefix is **C-b** and **C-b** is bound to `send-prefix` (so that hitting it twice sends a single **C-b** to the active pane). This is just what we need to access the bindings of the inner *tmux* instance.

The first **C-b** is captured by the “outer” *tmux* instance as its prefix key. The second one is captured by the “outer” *tmux* instance and triggers its **C-b** binding (`send-prefix`). This sends a **C-b** to the outer instance’s active pane. The process running in this pane is (ultimately, through an *ssh* instance) the “inner” *tmux* instance. It captures the **C-b** as its prefix key. Now your next keystroke will be passed through the outer *tmux* instance and captured by the inner one to trigger a binding.

To trigger the **c** binding (`new-window`) in a second-level instance of *tmux*, you would type **C-b C-b c**. For a third-level instance of *tmux* you would type **C-b C-b C-b C-b c**.

This doubling for each level can be annoying if you are commonly dealing with multiple layers of *tmux*. If you can spare some other key, you could make a non-prefixed binding to make things (possibly) easier to type:

```
bind-key -n C-\ send-prefix
bind-key -n C-^ send-prefix \; send-prefix
```

Create new window in second-level *tmux*: **C-\ c**
Create new window in third-level *tmux*: **C-^ c** (or **C-\ C-\ c**)

---

If you have a limited number of *tmux* commands that you want to (easily) send to the lower-level *tmux* instances, you might instead use `send-keys` to create some specific bindings (possibly just in your top-level *tmux* instance):

```
bind-key C-c  send-keys C-b c
bind-key C    send-keys C-b C-b c
```

Create new window in second-level *tmux*: **C-b C-c**
Create new window in third-level *tmux*: **C-b C**

Comment: Additionally I had to comment out my existing `last-window` binding as it was called when doing `C-a C-a`, as such: `#bind-key C-a last-window`. Note my prefix is `a`, not the default `b`.

Comment: `bind-key -n C-\ send-prefix` does not work. My tmux is not recognising the \. When I use a letter, it works.

Comment: @Darksky: What version of *tmux* are you using? It works for me with 1.7, 1.6, and 1.5. You will definitely need to add an extra level of quoting if you are making the binding from a shell command (i.e. `tmux bind-key -n 'C-\' send-prefix`); if you are having problems getting it to work from `~/.tmux.conf` (or a Prefix `:` command line), then you might try similar quoting (i.e. `bind-key -n 'C-\' send-prefix`).

Answer (score 74):

To access the inner, hold control and hit B twice.

Answer (score 9):

**EDIT:**

I do **NOT** recommend use **`C-q`** as a bind-key, as it is a default control-key command for

> un-freezes the screen and lets screen display continue

A situation happens [here](https://superuser.com/a/553349/191824), and @Paschalis provides a solution:

> if it happens to be twice unlucky (a remote tmux session with C-q as prefix): Type `Cltr-q`, then `:`, and enter in tmux: `send-keys C-q`

### Below it is the answer:

---

To make it simple, add the below line in your `~/.tmux.conf`

```
bind-key -n C-q send-prefix
```

Then you can **directly** use `C-q` as bind-key for your remote tmux.

Comment: if someone has changed the default binder key in the outer tmux, then has to use the same default binder key in the inner tmux, for the above snippet to work!

Comment: i am modifying the prefix of my local tmux (to Ctrl+] in my case) so all the "inner" tmux-es on the servers have default binding for prefix