# How do I remap prefix to C-x and retain the ability to send C-x to process?

Tags: tmux

I have the following code in my `.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g prefix C-x
unbind-key C-b
bind-key C-x send-prefix
```

And it works fine most of the time. But when I open `nano` to edit some files, I can't send `C-x` to it (exit command). What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason a single C-x command won't close `nano` in this case is because `tmux` is intercepting that prefix.

I found parts of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8530024/2390655) to be helpful, particularly:

> By default, the prefix is C-b and C-b is bound to send-prefix (so that hitting it twice sends a single C-b to the active pane)

Given your `.tmux.conf`, press C-x **twice** (either `C-x C-x` or `C-x-x`, not `C-x x`) to send a single C-x to the active pane. If `nano` is open in the active pane, it will be closed. I tested this on my end and it worked.

Comment: Strange - I tried pressing C-x twice when I was writing the question (this config was created exactly for that), and it didn't work at the time. Now I tried again - and it worked.