# How to send commands to nested tmux sessions from script

Tags: tmux

I have a tmux script to create nested tmux sessions

```
#!/bin/env tcsh
set SESSION=$1
set NESTED_SESSION=$2
\tmux -2 new-session -d -s ${SESSION}
\tmux send-keys "unsetenv TMUX" C-m
\tmux send-keys "\tmux -2 new-session -s ${NESTED_SESSION}" C-m
#i want some commands in the nested session

\tmux attach-session -t ${SESSION}
```

How do I pass the commands to the nested session. If i use send-keys they go to the original session and not the nested session.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think you want what's described in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518815/how-to-send-commands-when-opening-a-tmux-session-inside-another-tmux-session?rq=1

Comment: i can send the commands to the nested tmux using `Ctrl-bb` but i am not able to do it from a script.